# Javascript: Async and jQuery's document ready / DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I've about five scripts I need to load on a specific page. They're big libraries like `datatables` or `tinymce`. I've been doing some reading and I found out I could use `async` in order not to block the page from loading.

Some of my pages include code like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#title").on('input propertychange paste', function() {
        $("#slug").val(getSlug($(this).val()));
    });
});
</script>
```

This code needs the library previously loaded in order to work. Otherwise I'll get get an error saying a function is not available. — Happening right now.

My doubts are:

1. Doesn't `DOMContentLoaded` fires only after all my script are loaded, even if they're set as `async`?
2. Isn't jQuery's `$(document).ready()` supposed happen after `DOMContentLoaded`, then why my script fails?

If I'm wrong, how am I supposed to avoid the bottleneck caused by not loading the scripts asynchronously?

Thank you.

Comment: What function is not available?

Comment: Can you show how and where(example. head/body/footer) you are loading jquery and other scripts?

Comment: I'm loading the scripts on header... It doesn't work because `getSlug` is not available. That function is loaded from an external script with `async `.